# Overlapping of multiple plots with mathplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: Both the plots should look similar, but the content of the different request is overlapped with the plot on left side]I am building a web application using Django that has an option of plotting plots like histograms, scatterplots, bar charts etc

Using matplotlib lib, I am plotting the plots and rendering the plots to HTML pages.

```
plt.figure()
plt.title("xyz")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.plot(x,y, 'b')   
plt.plot(x,z, 'r')    
buf = BytesIO()
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(12,8, forward=True)
fig.savefig(buf, format='png')
plt.clf()

# Get Image
image_base64 = base64.b64encode(
    buf.getvalue()).decode('utf-8').replace('\n', '')

img_src = 'data:image/png;base64, {}'.format(image_base64)
```

When a user sends two different requests to plot different plots, the content like legend and data points are mixing with other plots and results in an overlap of plots. In the attached image, the plot on the left side should be similar to the plot on the right side. But the content of different plot request is appended to this response and being displayed in this response.

Answer (score 1):

Its because the `plt` is resused multiple times. Something like this should help..

```
def simple(request):
    import random
    import django
    import datetime

    from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

    fig=Figure()
    ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
    x=[]
    y=[]
    now=datetime.datetime.now()
    delta=datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    for i in range(10):
        x.append(now)
        now+=delta
        y.append(random.randint(0, 1000))
    ax.plot_date(x, y, '-')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
    response=django.http.HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)
    return response
```

<sub>[Source](https://gist.github.com/htygithub/a80d186c1ebdc236e936)</sub>

Comment: This is only a demo showcasing the use of matplotlib within django..feel free to customize it as per your needs

Comment: I am able to plot the image and render it to the HTML page. But if I have similar implementation in multiple types of plots and user is requesting them in parallel, the content of one response is mixing up with the content of another response as showin in the attached image in the query

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're **plotting** both graphs on the same **figure**. For matplotlib, this means: "*Here is ONE canvas, please draw TWO graphs on it*".

If you want them to be split, either:

- Use 2 separate figures (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/multiple_figs_demo.html)
- Use 2 subplots on the same figure (https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html)

Comment: Sorry, I haven't made it clear in the query, the issue is if am requesting a bar chart in one request by sending input X, Y, Z and requesting a scatterplot in another request  by sending input W, Y, Z
The contents of bar chart and scatterplot are mixing up. Displaying the scatterplot in barchart  and contents of barchart are displayed in scatterplot.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but with Flask. Simply insert
plt.close(), after plt.save. The problem is solved.

Comment: Where is plt.save?